# Logical Proof Simplification

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am constructing a formal proof for this set of logical hypotheses:

D,  D ∧ C ⇒ E,  Z ⇒ C ⊢ Z ⇒ E

I have used the deduction theorem / conditional proof to create the following hypotheses, taking Z from the conclusion to be another hypothesis:
H1 = D
H2 = D ∧ C ⇒ E
H3 = Z ⇒ C
H4 = Z
Conclusion = E

I'm trying to be "clever" by simplifying D ∧ C ⇒ E into just C ⇒ E so that I can then use Hypothetical Syllogism rather than modus ponens. Is that a valid simplification? Or can I only simplify D ∧ C when it's on its own (without ⇒ E)?

E.g. Can a conjunction be simplified when it's implying something else? Or can a conjunction only be simplified when it's on its own?

Comment: Are you maybe missing a $Z \Rightarrow G$ assumption?

Comment: My apologies, you're quite right. G is actually meant to be Z. Don't know how that got in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!  Here is an example to see why this is an invalid inference:

If I am male and unmarried, then I am a bachelor  (true)

Therefore, if I am male, I am a bachelor (false!)

This is why inference rules for operators can only be applied when that operator is the *main* operator, e.g. Simplification can only be applied when the main connective is a conjunction (and the Simplification is applied to that very conjunction of course!)

Comment: Ah yes! Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: OK, but that does mean that you cannot prove the Conclusion in your argument. I think DanielV is right: there is probably some other assumption you didn't put in your post.

Comment: I've corrected the original post. Now makes much more sense! xD

Comment: @Matthew Yes, now it is actually valid! And the proof is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

*If* you meant $\bbox[cornsilk, 0.25ex]{D~,~ (D ∧ C) \to E~,~ Z \to C ~\vdash~ Z \to E}$ then *this* is sound.

$$\begin{array}{l:ll}1 & D & H_1
\\ 2& (D \land C ) \to E & H_2
\\ 3& Z \to C & H_3
\\ \quad 3.1 & Z & A_1
\\ \quad 3.2 & C & 3,3.1,{\to}\mathsf E
\\ \quad 3.3 & D\land C & 1,3.2 , \wedge\mathsf I
\\ \quad 3.4 & E & 2, 3.3, {\to}\mathsf E
\\ 4 & Z\to E & 3.1,3.4,{\to}\mathsf I
\end{array}\\ \therefore D, (D\land C)\to E, Z\to C~\vdash~ Z\to E$$

> I'm trying to be "clever" by simplifying D ∧ C ⇒ E into just C ⇒ E so I can use Hypothetical Syllogism rather than modus ponens

No, you *cannot* simplify.   You are on the wrong side of the conditional to use conjunction elimination.   Instead argue that:
$$D, Z\to C~\vdash~ Z\to(C\land D)$$
Then use HS